# Use yq to parse property files data model

Tags: yaml, templating, yq

I have a YAML file like this

```
apiVersion: "v1alpha1"
kind: "Druid"
metadata:
  name: druid-dev-cluster
spec:
  common.runtime.properties: |
    # Zookeeper
    druid.zk.service.host=cluster-zk-0.cluster-zk
    druid.zk.paths.base=/druid
    druid.zk.service.compress=false
```

I want to replace one of the properties in the common.runtime.properties. Is this supported using yq?
When I try normally it fails

```
property=.spec.common.runtime.properties.druid.zk.service.host=cluster-zk-0.cluster-zk
OVERLAY= deploy/overlays/aws/common-runtime-properties.yaml
yq e "${property}" "$OVERLAY"/"$propertyType"

Error: Parsing expression: Lexer error: could not match text starting at 1:55 failing at 1:57.
        unmatched text: "ti"
```

This works for other properties like

```
apiVersion: "v1alpha1"
kind: "Druid"
metadata:
  name: druid-dev-cluster
spec:
  nodes:
    brokers:
      nodeType: "broker"
      druid.port: 8088
      ingressAnnotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "plb.v1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are:

- `|` is a YAML literal block scalar. Its content is a single scalar as far as YAML is concerned and hence you cannot path-select into it from yq.
- Also, the content of `|` is not YAML, but probably parsed as Java properties file. Therefore, you cannot parse it even with recursively calling `yq` on the scalar.
- Also, the path to the scalar is not `.spec.common.runtime.properties` but `.spec."common.runtime.properties"` – note how the second part is written as a single scalar in the YAML content, which is not equivalent to having multiple child mappings (even though some Java folks seem to believe that).

That being said, you can of course do something like

```sh
export NEW_VALUE=droggeljug
UPDATED_CONTENT=$(\
    yq e '.spec."common.runtime.properties"' test.yaml | \
    sed -re 's/(druid.zk.service.host=)[^\n]*/\1'"$NEW_VALUE"'/g' \
) yq e '.spec."common.runtime.properties" = strenv(UPDATED_CONTENT)' test.yaml
```

This uses `yq` to select the scalar containing the properties (line 3), uses `sed` to update the value `druid.zk.service.host` to the content of `NEW_VALUE` (line 4), stores the result in `UPDATED_CONTENT` (line 2) and then calls `yq` again updating the value to be the content of `UPDATED_CONTENT` (line 5).

Comment: This looks great. Will try it out and update this thread